# Is there a way to get my laptop to beep from within a bash script running on a remote server via SSH?

Tags: bash, ssh, remote-server, beep

I have a bash script that I have to regularly run on a remote server. Part of the script includes running a backup which takes a while, and after it has run, I have to hit "Y" to confirm that the backup worked before the script will continue.

I would like to know if there is a way to get my laptop to make a beep (or some sort of sound) when that happens. I know that `echo -e '\a'` makes a beep, but if I run it from within a script on the remote server, the beep happens on the remote server.

I have control of the script that is being run, so I could easily change it to do something special.

Comment: Is using `yes` to feed `Y` to the script without your intervention an option?

Comment: How exactly are you running the script? It's your terminal emulator that beeps when `\a` is written to its output.

Comment: No, we need to make sure the backup worked manually.

Comment: @chepner - your comment prompted me to write a test script and run it, and it works, so it must be something else going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could send the command through ssh back to your computer like:

```
ssh user@host "echo -e '\a'"
```

Just make sure you have [ssh key authentication](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/public-key-authentication) from your server to your computer so the command can run smoothly

Comment: It's not just me that runs the script, and I don't always run it from the same place unfortunately.

Comment: If that is the case, then you may want to have an additional script on the local computer, something like:
ssh user@server "bash -s" < ./remote_script.sh
echo "\a"

or

ssh user@server "remote_script.sh"
echo "\a"

Answer (score 0):

In my case the offered solutions with echo didn't work. I'm using a macbook and connect to an ubuntu system. I keep the terminal open and I'd like to be informed when a long running bash script is ready.

What I did notice is that if I shutdown the remote system then it will beep the macbook and show an alarm icon on the relevant tab. So I have now implemented a bit of dirty workaround:

```
sudo shutdown 1440 && shutdown -c
```

This will initiate the system to shutdown and will immediately cancel the request. And I do get the alarm beep + icon. You will need to setup sudo to allow the user to permit shutdown. As it was my own remote server it was no problem but could limit the usability for others.